# Wifi problem on an FS Amilo Li 1718, under 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, networking, connection, atheros

I am having trouble with my Qualcomm Atheros AR242x/542x wifi card in a FS Amilo Li1718.
It only connects sometimes, and the speed is low when it does.
Sometimes it does not even allow me to turn on the wifi, or doesn't see any wifi networks when I do know there are several accessible.

The card is supported, ss there any chance to fix this problem, or should I get hold of a new wifi card?